# How to limit the amount of characters in a Lua string

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

I have a question: how do I make the `lua_tostring` function limit the amount of entries.

For example 8 characters limit:

```
poppy_name = "command"; // OK, within the limit;
poppy_name = "commander"; // Fail, Is out of range, show a message the permitted limit.
```

I searched I couldn't find anymore, is there a way to limit the `lua_tostring`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lua_tolstring` to obtain the string length, then use `lua_error` or `luaL_error` if the string is too long.

```
size_t arg_len;
lua_tolstring(L, 1, &arg_len);
if (arg_len > 8) return luaL_error(L, "argument too long");
```

Comment: @MarcosSilva `size_t *myLen; lua_tolstring(L, 1, &myLen); if( myLen > 8 ) raise hell`

Comment: understand by your example hjpotter92, case solved. Thank you

Comment: @Marcos Silva if his answer helped you, accept it by pressing that green checkmark next to it, this is to help future users with the same problem to find the answer quicker.

Comment: Added an example to the answer, thank you @hjpotter92

Comment: It should be `size_t arg_len`, not `size_t *arg_len`. Unfortunately the edit to fix that is too short ...